# Modify response to get a list of IDs and not a list of dict when referencing ForeignKeys

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a simple app that creates and stores tickets. Those tickets can cross-references themselves, so I use a specific table to keep this kind of information. A greatly simplified table structure is like this:

```py
class Ticket(Base):
    """Ticket."""
    __tablename__ = "tickets"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement="auto")
    title = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    children_tickets = relationship(
        "TicketReferences",
        primaryjoin="Ticket.id == TicketReferences.parent_id",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )
    parents_tickets = relationship(
        "TicketReferences",
        primaryjoin="Ticket.id == TicketReferences.child_id",
        cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )


class TicketReferences(Base):
    """Tickets can be cross-referenced"""
    __tablename__ = "tickets_references"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement="auto")
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tickets.id"), nullable=False)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tickets.id"), nullable=False)
```

Then I declare the corresponding schemas for Pydantic:

```py
class TicketsReferences(BaseModel):
    parent_id: int
    child_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class TicketCreate(TicketBase):
    title: str
    parents_tickets: Optional[List[int]] = []
    children_tickets: Optional[List[int]] = []

class Ticket(TicketBase):
    id: int
    title: str
    parents_tickets: List[TicketsReferences]
    children_tickets: List[TicketsReferences]
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

So then I can create tickets with those POST bodies:

```json
# Creates a first ticket which id will be 1
{
  "title": "Foo",
  "parents_tickets": [],
  "children_tickets": [],
}

# Creates a second ticket referencing ticket 1 as a parent
{
  "title": "Bar",
  "parents_tickets": [1],
  "children_tickets": [],
}
```

The issue is when I request one of those ticket I get an overly complex structure for either `parents_tickets` or `children_tickets`:

```json
# Fetch ticket #2
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "bar",
  "parents_tickets": [
    {
      "parent_id": 1,
      "child_id": 2
    }
  ],
  "children_tickets": []
}
```

I'd like to get a list of id like this: `"parents_tickets": [1]` and that's it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is (as it is so often) to define your Pydantic model in terms of the schema you **actually want**. In this case, you should define the fields `parents_tickets` and `children_tickets` both as `list[int]` because that is what you want.

Then you can write a custom [`pre=True` field validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) that handles the case when the values of those lists are not integers but instances of your database mapper class. It will then simply extract the `id` value and pass it along.

Allow me to simplify the example even further. To avoid unnecessary dependencies I'll just define my pseudo-database model as a dataclass and use a simplified corresponding Pydantic model:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Mapping
from dataclasses import dataclass

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


@dataclass
class TicketDB:
    id: int
    title: str
    parents_tickets: list[TicketDB]
    children_tickets: list[TicketDB]


class TicketModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    parents_tickets: list[int]
    children_tickets: list[int]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

    @validator("parents_tickets", "children_tickets", pre=True, each_item=True)
    def id_only_from_obj(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, TicketDB):
            return v.id
        if isinstance(v, Mapping):
            return v["id"]
        return v  # let normal field validation take over
```

Demo:

```py
db_obj = TicketDB(
    2,
    "bar",
    parents_tickets=[TicketDB(1, "foo", [], [])],
    children_tickets=[TicketDB(3, "baz", [], [])],
)
model_obj = TicketModel.from_orm(db_obj)
print(model_obj.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "bar",
    "parents_tickets": [
        1
    ],
    "children_tickets": [
        3
    ]
}
```

Of course, if the field you are actually interested in has a name other than `id`, adapt that validator accordingly. This is just to demonstrate the principle.

As a bonus, the validator here will also handle dictionaries (and other mappings) passed to it correctly, which may or may not be useful, when for example parsing JSON.

Comment: Thanks, I could make it to work. Sadly, `isinstance(v, TicketsReferences)` always returns False (probably because the path of the object is not the same since it was created in another file) so I had to resort to two try/except.